# save the output of 'Set Variable' activity into a csv file [Azure Data Factory]

Tags: azure, csv, save, azure-data-factory

Azure Data Factory:
I´m trying to save some variables (messages as: pipeline error, pipeline success and pipeline date end) from ´set variable´ into a csv file on my blobstorage.
I created a table in blob storage and now i need to fill table rows with this informations from ´set variable´. At the end of the pipeline I´ll use Logic App to generate a PDF report.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673220/transfer-the-output-of-set-variable-activity-into-a-json-file-azure-data-fact/61376547?noredirect=1#comment120739615_61376547)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your variable as a data source in the copy activity and then you can set the sink to be a csv file/ blob storage/ ADLS etc.

i built a quick Demo :

[image: SaveDataFromSetVariableActivity]

Here , i saved the data in a **set variable activity** into a variable and i named it
"data" , in the copyData activity ,i chose the source to be a json (because my data is a json array , u can change it to csv if your data is csv)
after that i clicked on : File Path Type -> List Of Files -> Path to File List -> @variables("data")

**Question** :

Why you're using a csv to describe your pipeline status ? why not just a simple json ? it will be easier to parse + understand the data in a json format.