# ADF Copy Activity with Additional Columns is Not working

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

My goal is to add some text to a file.
I used [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673220/transfer-the-output-of-set-variable-activity-into-a-json-file-azure-data-fact) to help me design this setup.

I have a set variable that sets a variable with some value. I then have a copy activity. This copy activity has an empty file for the source. I then add in an additional column that uses my set variable. In sink I have a different file I hope to copy the contents of set variable to. When I run in debug mode, the sink file ends up empty. The additional column is not being copied over. I tried with a mapping and then without. In both cases the same thing happened.
[image: Set Variable]
[image: Copy Activity Source]
[image: Copy Activity Sink]
[image: Copy Activity Mapping]

Does anyone have any ideas or tips?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and also seen the same empty data in the sink file as you mentioned.

[image]

Sink file:

[image]

You can raise the support ticket or feel free to post your question in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html) forum where the product team will monitor them closely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the file based copy activity is supposed to work this way, you need input data/rows for it to enumerate. If you have access to SQL server then you could simulate a dynamic SQL query to include the contents of your variable as a tabular output. This can then define a source set of rows that could be appended into a file.

For example, SQL for **Source Query**:

```sql
/*
    Bring in the value from your variable. use @@ to escape the SQL parameter name
    NOTE: Do not forget to escape single quotes if they exist in your string, replace ' with ''
*/
declare @@my_sql_var nvarchar(max) = '@{variables('fileContents')}';

/*
    Do some work here with this variable 
*/

/*
    Return the tabular response for the copy activity source query.
*/

select @@my_sql_var [VariableName];
```

**Copy Activity - SQL Source**

[image]

**Dynamic Expression for Source Query**

[image]

**Preview Output**

[image]