# Azure Data Factory: Cannot save the output of Set Variable into file/Database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to store a list of file names within an Azure Blob container into a SQL db. The pipeline runs successfully, but after running the pipeline, it cannot output the values (file names) into the sink database, and the sink table doesn't get updated even after the pipeline completed. Followings are the steps I went through to implement the pipeline. I wonder which steps I made mistake.

I have followed the solutions given in the following links as well:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy

[Transfer the output of 'Set Variable' activity into a json file [Azure Data Factory]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673220/transfer-the-output-of-set-variable-activity-into-a-json-file-azure-data-fact/61376547?noredirect=1#comment120739615_61376547)

Steps:
1- Validating File Exists, Get Files metadata and child items, Iterate the files through a foreach.

[image: Overview of pipeline]

2- Variable defined at the pipeline level to hold the filenames
Variable Name: Files, Type: string

3- parameter defined to dynamically specify the dataset directory name. Parameter name: dimName, parameter type: string

4- Get Metadata configurations

[image: Metadata Configs]

5- Foreach settings
@activity('MetaGetFileNames').output.childItems

6 - Foreach Activity overview. A set Variable to set the each filename into the defined variable 'files'. Copy Activity to store the set value into db.

[image: Foreach Activity Overview]

7- set variable configuration

[image: set variable]

8- Copy Activity source configuration. Excel Dataset refers to an empty excel file in azure blob container.

[image: copy Activity source config]

9- Copy Activity sink configuration

[image: copy activity sink]

10-Copy Activity: mapping configuration

[image: copy activity - mapping]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of selecting an empty excel file, refer to a dummy excel file with dummy data.

**Source**: dummy excel file

[image]

2. You can skip using Set variable activity as you can use the Foreach current item directly in the Additional column dynamic expression.

[image]

3. Add additional columns in the Mapping.

[image]

4. Sink results in SQL database.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I replaced the empty file, by referring a file that has some dummy values and the issue is resolved.

Comment: The dummy file should only have two rows, exactly as shown in the @NiharikaMoola-MT answer. Otherwise the values will be copied by the number of rows in the dummy file.