# how to set the output of set variable activity into JSON format in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

There are three set variables activity in my pipeline returning three Ids namely ID0, ID1 and ID2. I would like to combine their output into a new set variable activity whose output has a json format as shown below:

```
{"Data": 
{
"ID0": "ABC",
"ID1": "2022",
"ID2": "1234",
}
}
```

I have looked into the other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673220/transfer-the-output-of-set-variable-activity-into-a-json-file-azure-data-fact) asked here but most of them addresses the concern of converting / storing the output in a Json file. I am not willing to export any output to Json file rather just use it as a variable to feed in to another pipelines.

Comment: Why do you want to convert in json to pass variables to another pipeline you can directly create variables or parameter in that pipeline ad use that.

Comment: @PratikLad I want to send a message to a service bus pipeline that requires to read a Json input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new Set Variable activity, and used the following expression to combine all three variables:

```
{{"Data":{"ID0":"@{variables('ID_0')}","ID1":"@{variables('ID_1')}","ID2":"@{variables('ID_2')}"}}}
```

That gave me the following result in the Json format:

```
{
"name": "ouput",
"value": "{{\"Data\":{\"ID0\":\"ABC\",\"ID1\":\"2022\",\"ID2\":\"1234\"}}}"
}
```

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-zwBz8ZDt4) was helpful in creating the expression.