# How to Create and append a column from one JSON to another in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

This is my Pipeline

[image]

The Output from LookupDatModel is Below

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "ID": 71431952,
            "isProtected": null
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "selfhostedintegrationRuntime1",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ],
        "totalBillableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 2
    }
}
```

and the Output from DowdloadTextract is below

```
{
    "Response": "Research Report:   ",
    "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
        "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
        "Date": "Fri, 09 Feb 2024 10:10:52 GMT",
        "ETag": "\"3158c67d61:0\"",
        "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/7.0",
        "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
        "Content-Length": "77452",
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Last-Modified": "Thu, 29 Oct 2020 03:24:12 GMT"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "selfhostedintegrationRuntime1",
    "executionDuration": 2,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 2
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The Output we need is to append `DownloadTextract` columns value to `LookupDataModel`

So the Final Output that i would like to save in Storage is

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "ID": 71431952,
            "isProtected": null,
            **"Response": "Research Report:   "**
        }
    ]
}
```

Please suggest is there any way to do this .
For now I am saving both output to Storage because i did not get any way to combine then .
When i append  the complete json gets appended .

The Concatenation `@concat(activity('DownloadTextract').output.Response, activity('LookupDataModel').output.value)`
gives me below output

```
{
    "name": "v1",
    "value": "Research Report:  30  [{\"f_ID\":71431952,\"f_isProtected\":null}]"
}
```

Expected Output

```
{
    "name": "v1",
    "value": [{\"f_ID\":71431952,\"f_isProtected\":null,\"Response\":"Research Report:  30  "}]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the output of both the activity using `concat function` and then you can copy the result data to the blob storage. Below is the approach.

- Connect the output of Lookup activity and web activity to Set variable activity upon success of those two activities.

[image]

- The expression `@concat(activity('Downloadtextract').output.Response, activity('LookupDataModel').output.value)`  is used to join the results of both output. You can format the result as required using the functions in ADF.
- Then to copy the output of set variable to Json file, you can use copy activity. Refer the [answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61376547/19986107)

Comment: I am able to concatenate but formatting is what i need help in .I am also able to save to Storage .

Comment: Please have look at my updated question

Comment: This kind of formatting is not possible in ADF expression. We can join both the result as string only. If you expect the result to be of Json, you may consider using dataflow transformation